# Is SLO in SAML is supposed to work across different browsers?

Tags: java, saml-2.0, spring-saml, adfs2.0

I want to know the what is really happening with Spring SAML for SP and testing it with ADFS as the IDP, As the SLO that I am expecting is not happening.

- Spring Boot Version : 2.1.8.RELEASE
- Java version : 1.8
- ADFS version : 2.0

Note: I am using a single user credentials on all the different browsers Ex : *user/user@123*

I am following below steps to achieve the SSO

1. Get list of IDP from SP
2. Select and login in one of the IDP with the given IDP login page
3. IDP sends a request to `/saml/SSO`
4. Authentication successful and the session starts

Now in this process whenever I open an another SP and try to login with the same IDP it logs me in automatically.

For SLO below are the steps I am following

1. I am initiating a SLO request by hitting the SP at `/saml/logout` that is further handled by `SAMLLogoutFilter`
2. Session is invalidated
3. I see a LogoutRequest in the logs of all the SP's logged in on the browser A.
4. Logout successful, Now it asks for credentials for all the SP's in the browser A.

When I try SSO on different browsers it asks for credentials once for each browser on the first SP and the rest of the SP's are logged in automatically which I can understand as other browsers has no data of the user session to which the user wants to login, but after all the SP's are logged in from different browsers, I guess IDP knows the connected SP's and as per my understanding it should logout all the SP's across the browser when a SLO is initiated from any of the SP.

But the problem is when a SLO is initiated from the browser A, I see logout requests as well as the SP's are logged out only  those were logged in on the same browser A and the rest browsers B and C SP's are still logged in and they do not ask for the credentials if the `/saml/logout` is not initiated explicitly for that browser instance

SLO Example

SP1, SP2 are logged in with Browser A

SP3 logged in with Browser B

SP4 and SP5 are logged in with Browser C

SLO initiated from Brower A - SP2 then SP1 is logged out but SP3,4 and 5 are still logged in

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think there's a way we can log out the user from other apps(SP3,4,5 in your example) because they are owned by different parties. I can think of one way - that is check for an active session on IDP when SP3,4,5 sends requests.

Comment: I don't think that is an option refer https://www.componentspace.com/Forums/9033/Check-Session-is-available-at-IDP it says 'The SAML specification doesn't include a mechanism for checking whether the user has an authentication session at the IdP.', But yes of course if there is a way I would like to check if any of the SP has initiated a SLO

Comment: If a front channel binding is used  to send out the logout requests by the IdP to all the other session particiants, it can not work (as the SPs may not find the related session ... most of the use cookies). However when a back channel binding is used then it should work.